# How to write to a named range of non-adjacent cells in excel using .NET

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I can use a 2D array to write to a named range of adjacent cells.

```
worksheet.range("namedRangeAdjacentCells").value = TwoDArray(n,0)
```

When I write to a named range of non-adjacent cells, the value of every cell in the range is equal to the first element of the 2D array.  I am writing 7 values per worksheet to 20 worksheets and it takes a while to output the workbook when the range function is called 7 times.

Comment: You need a loop to write to the non-contiguous areas of the named range.

Comment: @BigBen As in calling the range() function every loop iteration?  I wanted to do it in one shot like I do for the range of continuous cells.

Comment: You can't, sorry.